# What components in Tomcat architecture avoid scalability?

Tags: performance, tomcat, architecture, scalability, servlet-container

I need to know what components in Tomcat servlet container avoids scalability. In Tomcat clustering, what components(Server, Engine, etc.) in it's architecture have problem in terms of scalability?

I hope I could explain my question clearly.